# Can you square a semi partial correlation when it is negative?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, spss

For example, I have a b: -.940  beta: -1.649  sig .000 and part(semipartial) of -.505 in a group of 5 independent variables. What does the negative sr mean and do I square it to get the strength of prediction of the IV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correlation in general the semipartial correlation gives you the direction of the association by the sign and the strength by the magnitude. A negative semipartial correlation means that there is a negative association between the variables decreasing the response variable by 0.405 (in your case) with every increase in Y, given all other predictors in the model are held constant.
You may square the sr. Most of the time $sr^2$ actually is what you need. It gives you the uniquely explained variance in Y by X given all other predictors in the model. That is it gives you information on how much the explained variance increases of your model if you add this variable. sr's are additive:

$R^2=sr_1+sr_2+...+sr_k$

I hope this helps.